# Testing map with timestamp value in Clojure

Tags: unit-testing, testing, clojure, timestamp

I am testing a function in Clojure which takes a map as input and outputs a map to which the field `:timestamp (current-timestamp)` is added.

I have problems testing for equality as I cannot predict which timestamp will be added by the function.

```clj
(is (= output (convert-map input)))
```

I thought about `dissoc`-ing the `:timestamp` from the output of the function but that seems convoluted, so I wonder if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the fn `with-redefs`, and make the fn you're using to get the timestamp always return the same timestamp when testing.

```clj
(with-redefs [timestamp-fn (constantly "2019-07-28T12:00:00Z")]
  (your-fn params))
```

You can read about it here: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-redefs

Answer (score 1):

Clojure's [metadata](https://clojure.org/reference/metadata) feature was designed with this in mind. It provides a way to store information about some data that is independent of the data itself.

```
user> (defn convert-map [input]
        (with-meta input {:timestamp (clj-time.core/now)}))
#'user/convert-map

user> (convert-map {:a 1 :b 1})
{:a 1, :b 1}

user> (def input {:a 1 :b 1})
#'user/input

user> (def output (convert-map {:a 1 :b 1}))
#'user/output

user> (:timestamp (meta output))
#object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x29eb7744 "2019-07-25T15:36:16.609Z"]

user> (= input output)
true
```

This preserves all equality concepts. It is very useful to keep in mind that the metadata is attached to a particular data so if you do something that copies the contents from input into some other data structure then this metadata would not come along as in this example:

```
user> (meta (merge output {:c 0}))
{:timestamp
 #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x29eb7744 "2019-07-25T15:36:16.609Z"]}

user> (meta (merge {:c 0} output))
nil
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is close to what I need. However, if I test a function that formats the map with a timestamp and compare the output after applying the `convert-to-map` function, the `:timestamp` key does not get overridden as a meta key and the equality check still fails in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the timestamp, or provide a way of making (current-timestamp) produce a known value rather than clock time.